# Designinig SASS I want Box layout but not able to get it

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, sass, styling

Like I'm trying to get this layout [image]

```
<div>
  {iconElement}
  <div className='id-count-title'>
    {title}     
    <div className='id-count-description'>
      {description}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried writing CSS and giving styling to it,

```
.id-count-title {
  width: 37px;
  height: 32px;
  left: 443px;

    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;

    color: #4CA6EA;
}

.id-count-description {
    width: 58px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 432px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

with this styling class I'm getting [image]

How can I achieve the styling required?

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox, here is a guide of flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Make your container **display: flex** and **justify-content: space-around** or **space-between** as what you prefer.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: #135;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex span {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.flex .active {
  color: #4CA6EA;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="active"><span>18</span>Users</div>
  <div><span>1</span>Native</div>
  <div><span>17</span>Non-native</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is exactly what you need.
You can change your code by this way:

html:

```
<div className="id-block">
  <div className="icon">
    {iconElement}
  </div>
  <div className="text">
    <div className='id-count-title'>
      {title}
    </div>
    <div className='id-count-description'>
      {description}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css/sass:

```
.id-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.id-count-title {
    width: 37px;
    height: 32px;
    left: 443px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #4CA6EA;
}

.id-count-description {
    width: 58px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 432px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}
```